# Правая рука, вторая голова(,) – как только не называют мобильный телефон

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Надо ли ставить запятую перед тире? **В каких отношениях находятся первая и вторая части предложения, разделенные тире?**

Answer (score 3):

Запятую ставить не нужно. Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

> «Плевок в вечность», «Деньги кончились, а позор остался» ― как только не называла она свою киношку. [Алексей Щеглов. Фаина Раневская: вся жизнь (2003)]
>
> Романтика, авантюра, безрассудство ― как только не говорили о его безумной идее пересечь Атлантический океан на папирусной лодке. [Мария Киселева, Елена Строителева. Тура Хейердала похоронят по-божески (2002) // «Известия», 2002.04.19]
>
> Сейчас человека-амфибию, фишемэна (человека-рыбу), фрогмэна (человека-лягушку) ― как только не называют спортсменов-подводников ― можно встретить во всех уголках нашей планеты. [В. Сташевский. Начало подводной эры // «Спортсмен-подводник», 1966]

Comment: А как Вы определяете грамматику этого предложения, ведь его надо привязать к какому-то правилу.

Comment: Это именительный темы. "Однако при именительном темы, более тесно связанном с основным предложением, в котором имеется личное или указательное местоимение в качестве слова-отсылки, ставится тире: Марченко – тот был человек, золотой человек (Каз.); Дорога в дождь – она не сладость, дорога в дождь – она беда (Евт.).

Примечание. Допустимо используемое в практике печати и написание с запятой: Врач, он ведь тоже не Бог (Бык.); Судьбы человеческие, они – каждая сама по себе... Наташа, та знала, что за человек ее тетя (Бит.) https://orfogrammka.ru

Comment: Jasmin, Юлия, насчет грамматики предложения я не уверен. И не думаю, что здесь именительный темы. Скорее перечисление, которое стоит перед обобщающими словами.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не нужно, ведь у в предложении нет кавычек прямой речи. Также запятая была бы, если бы имелся оборот, требующий обособления. В приведённом примере запятая разделяет два однородных члена. Третьего нет, соответственно, никакой функции запятая перед тире не несла бы.